# How to use #define to assign pins in Arduino?

Tags: macros, arduino, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use `#define` to create a constant and define a pin, check this code

```
#define PIN_MICROPHONE 13;

void loop()
{
    analogRead(PIN_MICROPHONE);
}
```

But when trying to compile, it says this error:

```
: In function 'void loop()':
error: expected `)' before ';' token
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
error: expected `;' before ')' token
```

How can I use `#define` macros to define pins?

This code compiles ok

```
#define PIN_MICROPHONE 13;

void loop()
{
    analogRead(13);
}
```

I am using Arduino 1.0.5

Comment: Arduino language is **more** like Java, not C (it supports `class` uses).

Comment: how that would help me in this problem?

Comment: another semicolon sighting, no one is free ...

Comment: very true my friend :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is your semicolon.

`#define` does not require a semicolon on the end of it.

```
#define PIN_MICROPHONE 13
void loop()
{
    analogRead(PIN_MICROPHONE);
}
```

Typically the #define is a pre-compiled directive. That means before the code is compiled a find and replace is done on the text. So the IDE "saw" the code below.

```
void loop()
{
    analogRead(13;); //not going to work 
}
```

PS: I thought `#define`s were not encouraged in Arduino style guides.

Comment: #defines are fine ;-) http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define though apparently **const** is preferred.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so noob right now..., I have years of experience coding in C, C++, I'm very surprised right now, how could this happen to me...
thank you John b, I believe I need to rest a little :)